# Can any queuing system trigger external Applications

Tags: rabbitmq, activemq-classic, msmq, message-queue, zeromq

Right now  we have a queuing system(activemq) which is storing the messages. And we have written a separate java application that will read the queue and then trigger a exe to do some processing. But we want to do away with this extra application that is linking our activemq and exe. So i want to know whether any queuing system houses a code which will help me run the exe without any extra code written by me.

Any inputs regarding which queuing system can get me this done will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your actual requirement? The question is very non-specific.

Comment: @hugh please look at the modified query. I hope i am more specific this time around

Comment: OK that's more understandable. However, unfortunately I can't think of any way that this could work with the queuing platforms I'm familiar with

Comment: How would you imaging interacting with this code?  Are you looking for a way to just add the exe somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really how Message Brokers work.  You could however embed a broker inside your own application or create a broker plugin to do something.  In the end though the best way to do this is to create your own client that can implement your business logic and let the Message Broker do what it was designed to do, route message traffic.

Comment: can you tell me,every one using `sender,consumer` words.That means sender,consumers are another programs(like Java program using JMS).

Answer (score 1):

If you want more of a 'push' solution rather than a producer-consumer solution (which sounds to me like you are) you could look into the use of WebSockets. That would be another way of dealing with messages.

As others have said it doesn't look like using a message broker is the solution you want if you don't want to have some additional middleware to provide asynchronous communication.

Answer (score 0):

So you just need something to launch an EXE on message arrival?

[Message Queuing Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just some additional information for you... Triggered applications are natively supported in IBM Websphere MQ via a Trigger Monitor application that runs as a service (in windows implementations) or a daemon (in UNixish implementations).

When a message arrives in a queue, the MQ software will generate another message ("Trigger" message and send it to the "Trigger" queue, which is being monitored by the Trigger Manager app. The app then starts the required application.

So your implementation of an "app to start an app" is not odd ball or strange at all.. IBM do it in their implementation. I see nothing wrong with your implementation and if you can integrate it tighter to activeMQ then you are on a winner.

Answer (score 0):

What about IBM MQ's triggering feature ?

> WebSphere MQ provides a feature that enables an application or channel to be started automatically when there are messages available to retrieve from a queue. A message is put to a queue defined as triggered. If a series of conditions are met, the queue manager sends a trigger message to an initiation queue.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q026940_.htm